# Cant reach LDAP server from dockerized Nexus Repository

Tags: docker, ldap, nexus

We are using OSS 3.27.0-03 version of Nexus RM inside docker container.

I’m currently trying to configure LDAP authentication but I’m stuck on the very beginning:

Failed to connect to LDAP Server: XXXXX:389 [Caused by java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXXX]

When I test the connection from the container itself using: ldapsearch and same credentials I use in Nexus - it works fine.

Any ideas guys ?

```
2021-03-10 09:57:01,995+0000 ERROR [qtp219612199-555]  swadmin org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectExceptionHandler - Failed to invoke action method: ldap_LdapServer.verifyConnection, java-method: org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.internal.ui.LdapServerComponent.verifyConnection
java.lang.Exception: Failed to connect to LDAP Server: XXX:389 [Caused by java.net.UnknownHostException: XXX]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:250)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.internal.ui.LdapServerComponent.verifyConnection(LdapServerComponent.groovy:183)
    at com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.java:23)
    at com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.TimedInterceptor.invoke(TimedInterceptor.java:26)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.validation.internal.ValidationInterceptor.invoke(ValidationInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.proceed(AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.java:49)
    at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.invoke(AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.proceed(AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.java:49)
    at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.invoke(AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: The request can not find the host XXXXX. (ie. UnknownHostException)

Comment: The thing is that Nexus app can connect/find host while its working fine from container from same data :/

Answer (score 0):

Guess it was DNS issue - adding entry to etc/hosts solved my problem.